# Sample Code for Text.IO.ReadAll

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have to read json files from 30 `GCS` folders into a dataflow pipline as String. Instead of adding a `Text.IO.Read` step for each I was hoping to use [Text.IO.ReadAll](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.ReadAll.html). Any ideas how I can set it up for reading from multiple folders.

Found [this](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.html) but the name of folders in my case is in a `List<String>` not a `PCollection<String>`

```
// E.g. the filenames might be computed from other data in the pipeline, or
 // read from a data source.
 PCollection<String> filenames = ...;

 // Read all files in the collection.
 PCollection<String> lines = filenames.apply(TextIO.readAll());
```

Each GCS folder I have to read has 500 files.

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. Eg did you try converting from Pcollection to List? You want to have lines from 30 sources being pumped to one List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Create.of() to create a PCollection from a List.

Comment: Any ideas how to return `PCollection<TableRow>` from `TextIO.ReadAll` I have currently `PCollection<String> pCollection = pipeline.apply(Create.of(stringList));` then `pCollection.apply(TextIO.readAll());` but this returns `PCollection<String>` not a `PCollection<TableRow>`

Comment: Use Map, FlatMap, or ParDo to convert from String to TableRow.